# Display the Output in the same textbox in visual studio

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

When i am giving the details, it will print in the new text box whatever values i am assigning, but i want to print the same values which i am giving in the textbox itself. I am using [httppost] and [httpGet] commands for this.

in View page i have this code :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "LoginPage";
}
<h1>LoginPage</h1>
 <form  method="post" action="/Home/LoginPage" >
     <table>
         <tr>
             <td>First Name : </td>
             <td><input type="text" id="txt.Fname" name="F_FIRSTNAME" class="form-control"/> </td> 
          </tr>
         <tr>
             <td> Last Name : </td>
             <td><input type="text" id="txt_LNAME" name="L_LastName" class="form-control"/></td> 
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Password: </td> 
             <td><input type="password" id="txt_Password" name="P_PASSWORD" class="form-control" /> </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Email ID : </td>
             <td><input type="email" id="txt_emailid" name="E_EmailID" class="form-control" /> </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td><input type="submit" id="txt_Enter" name="Enter" class="btn-primary" /></td>
         </tr>
     </table>
 </form>

@{ 
    if(IsPost==true)
    {
        string name1 = Request["F_FIRSTNAME"]; 
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name1))
        {
            <h2 style=" color:aquamarine;" > <input type="text" value="@name1" /> </h2>
        }
        string name2 = Request["L_LASTNAME"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name2))
        {
            <h2 style="color:blue;"> <input type="text" value="@name2" /> </h2>
        }
        string name3 = Request["P_PASSWORD"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name3))
        {
            <h2 style="color:blue;"> <input type="text" value="@name3" /> </h2>
        }
        string name4 = Request["E_EMAILID"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name4))
        {
            <h2 style="color:blue;"> <input type="text" value="@name4" /></h2>
        }
        else
        {
            <h5>This is a get request </h5>
        }
    }

}
```

and in controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication3.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult LoginPage()
        {
            return View(); 
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AfterLoginPage(string F_FIRSTNAME, stringL_LASTNAME, string P_PASSWORD, string E_EMAILID)
        {
             return View("LoginPage");
        }
    }
}
```

[As you can see the credentials are displaying in separate text box which i created but i want to display it on the same text box ][enter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmdLA.png)

Comment: I think you are making it complicated. Simpy use a view model and use the `TextBoxFor` method inside your form. No need of that `if-else` conditional displaying etc.

Comment: Yes, if the information has to enterred from the user so how can we do using ViewBag or View Data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can change your form and replace the code below:

```
<form method="post" action="/Home/LoginPage">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>First Name : </td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txt.Fname" name="F_FIRSTNAME" class="form-control" value="@(IsPost ? Request["F_FIRSTNAME"]:"")" /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Last Name : </td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txt_LNAME" name="L_LastName" class="form-control" value="@(IsPost ? Request["L_LastName"]:"")" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password: </td>
                <td><input type="password" id="txt_Password" name="P_PASSWORD" class="form-control" value="@(IsPost ? Request["P_PASSWORD"]:"")"/> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email ID : </td>
                <td><input type="email" id="txt_emailid" name="E_EmailID" class="form-control" value="@(IsPost ? Request["E_EmailID"]:"")"/> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" id="txt_Enter" name="Enter" class="btn-primary" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</form>
```

And you can remove the rest of `View` code. I haven't tested it but I guess it works, although it's not the proper solution. It's better to have a separate `Model` or `ViewModel` for that.